# How to add download image in website?

Tags: html, download

I am trying to put a image in my website for Download. I am link the image url directly.

```
<a href="http://example.com/downloads/brand-logo.png">Click Here to Download</a>
```

The image is open in browser. I need if click the image link that will be download to system?

Answer (score 4):

Change it to this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/downloads/brand-logo.png" download>Click Here to Download</a>
```

Adding the `download` attribute to an anchor tag, downloads the file from the `href` attribute

Comment: It is also possible to set the `Content-Disposition` header, see [rfc6266](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266).